# Is there any ways to make coroutines fps independent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a coroutine to animate the fading effect on my objects material.

```
public IEnumerator DissolveIn()
{
    float elapsed = 0f;
    while (elapsed < 1)
    {
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Material mat = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
            float fade = math.lerp(mat.GetFloat("_Fade"), .8f, .22f);
            mat.SetFloat("_Fade", fade);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        Material mat = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
        mat.SetFloat("_Fade", 1f);
    }
}
```

The problem is the speed of the animation is changing with the fps changes. If someone plays the game with 30 fps the animation becomes slow. And for someone with 200 fps it is too fast to even see what is happening.

Is there any way for me to make this fps independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use delta time, but compute `elapsed` based on the animation's start time and the current time, something like this. You can also get rid of the final `for` loop by doing it within the animation loop:

```
public IEnumerator DissolveIn()
{
    float startTime = Time.time;
    while (true)
    {
        float elapsed = Math.min(1, Time.time - startTime);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Material mat = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
            float fade = math.lerp(mat.GetFloat("_Fade"), .8f, .22f);
            mat.SetFloat("_Fade", fade);
        }
        if (elapsed >= 1)
            break;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AKX's answer you can also use `fixed update`, it's speed is hardware dependant but is regular:

```
public IEnumerator DissolveIn()
{
    WaitForFixedUpdate wait = new WaitForFixedUpdate(); // for performance reasons, avoids garbage collection each yield
    float elapsed = 0f;
    while (elapsed < 1)
    {
        elapsed += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Material mat = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
            float fade = math.lerp(mat.GetFloat("_Fade"), .8f, .22f);
            mat.SetFloat("_Fade", fade);
        }
        yield return wait;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        Material mat = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;
        mat.SetFloat("_Fade", 1f);
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html

Comment: It is not a good idea to make such things in the FixedUpdate.